Javascript - Await not waiting in async function returning a promise
I've recently started learning javascript and I'm having a big problem understanding the async behavior of the language. I've spent hundreds of hours searching and everyone recommends the use of promises but I can't quite comprehend what I'm doing wrong (maybe all of it lol).
I tried with promises as recommended by almost everyone in every forum and came up with this code but somehow I can't manage to make it wait for function1 to be finished in function2, since I get that promise1 is undefined.
 async function function1() {
    let query = "SELECT * FROM table1";

    connection.query(query, (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("Length " result.rows.length);

        let result_query = [];
        let i = 0;
        while (i < result.rows.length) {
            result_query.push(result.rows[i]);
            i++;
        }

    let customPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(result_query.length > 0){
            resolve(result_query);
        } else {
            reject(new Error('ERROR'))
        }
        });
    customPromise.then(() => {
        return customPromise;
    });
};

async function function2() {
    promise1 =  await function1();
    promise1.then(function(){ //HERE I GET THAT PROMISE1 IS UNDEFINED
        console.log("Exit");
    })
}

This is my original code where I realized javascript has an asynchronous nature and it prints "Exit" in function2 before function1 is finished. I'm sorry if this is an obvious question but I feel stuck. Thank you all for your kindness in helping strangers.
async function function1() {
    let query = "SELECT * FROM table1";

    connection.query(query, (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("Length " result.rows.length); //*THIS PRINTS AFTER THE EXIT IN FUNCTION2

        let result_query = [];
        let i = 0;
        while (i < result.rows.length) {
            result_query.push(result.rows[i]);
            i++;
    }

    if(result_query.length > 0){
        return(result_query);
    } else {
        return("ERROR");
    }
};

async function function2() {
    function1();
    console.log("Exit"); //*THIS PRINTS BEFORE EVERYTHING
}

OUTPUT:
> Exit
> Length 2


The first mistake is not recognizing the db callback function is asynchronous—that’s where the promise resolution needs to happen—when you actually have the data.

function1(); returns a promise you must await, but await function1() is the result of the promise.  so promise1 =  await function1(); is wrong.  Also, where is the ) that matches the ( in connection.query( in the last block of code ??  There's an indentation error in your code.

What is this database API? pg? pg supports promises out of the box.

Dave, I got it now, I'm just learning about asynchronism and it makes perfect sense now. I followed Nicholas example and it worked great! Thank you so much for your comments.

Wyck, I made a mistake when copy-pasting parts of my code, I'm sorry about that! I followed Nicholas example and worked great. Now I just need to keep programming and making mistakes to learn more about it. Thanks a lot!

Ry, is a pg database. I was told the same by Nicholas and it makes perfect sense but it was also a good example to learn how to create and properly use my own promises. Thanks a lot for your comments and help!

connection.query(query, (error, result) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Length ", result.rows.length);

  let result_query = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < result.rows.length) {
    result_query.push(result.rows[i]);
    i++;
  }
});

This piece of code is using callbacks for its asynchronous code. If you want to convert it into promises, you will need to do that here. Something like this:
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.query(query, (error, result) => {
    if (error) reject(error);
    else resolve(result);
  });
})
const result = await promise; 

let result_query = [];
let i = 0;
while (i < result.rows.length) {
  result_query.push(result.rows[i]);
  i++;
}

That loop doesn't actually appear to do much: it's just copying the rows to a separate array, but you could just use the rows directly. So i'd recommend removing it, which makes the full function this:
async function function1() {
  let query = "SELECT * FROM table1";

  const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, (error, result) => {
      if (error) reject(error);
      else resolve(result);
    });
  });

  if (result.rows.length > 0) {
    return result.rows;
  } else {
    return "ERROR";
  }
}

Then to use it, you can do this:
async function function2() {
  const rows = await function1();
  console.log("Exit");
}


P.S: you didn't mention what library the connection variable is from, but most libraries these days support promises. So if connection.query is built to return a promise, you don't need to wrap it in a new promise of your own.
const result = await connection.query(query);


Oh thank you so much. This actually helped a lot understanding my mistakes. Waiting for the query to resolve was my main mistake and now it works perfectly. I promise to keep working hard on learning about promises (see what I did there? lol). Thank you everyone in the comments, everything you said helped me understand that I'm doin some things wrong, I deeply appreciate your time and your help.
